# libsodium segment fault on ARMv5

Tags: c, arm, libsodium

I can use libsodium 1.0.7 just fine in Ubuntu but there seems to be some issue when trying to cross-compile the libsodium library to an armv5 architecture (`armv5tejl-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`).
I have used `./configure --host=armv5tejl-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`  and then `make DESTDIR=/home/myself/ARM/`.

All files are generated fine (headers and static & shared library files) and I can compile and link a small test C-program which then generates a segmentation fault when it's executed on my ARMv5 target (toolchain and all is  fine, everything else I compile & link not using libsodium runs perfectly fine on my ARM machine):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "sodium.h"
int main()
{
  printf("sodium_init()=%d\n",sodium_init()); // Fine, = 0
  unsigned char pbk[crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
  unsigned char sbk[crypto_box_SECRETKEYBYTES];
  crypto_box_keypair(pbk,sbk); // <-- Segmentation fault.
}
```

I have also tried the official cross-compile for ARM instructions at https://download.libsodium.org/doc/installation/index.html but configure fails due to a missing `nosys.specs` file. Is there somewhere I can download this (I have goggled it and it seems that it has to be specifically generated for the libsodium package)?

Comment: Just to be sure, you should show the `#include`s as well so to make your example self-contained. Maybe the problem is there?

Comment: Hi !
You're completely  right, here are the includes :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "sodium.h"

The same simple source compiles and executes in the host machine (Ubuntu 15) with sodium built for Ubuntu) but not in the target ARMv5 system (with the sodium library files built for the ARMv5 system)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting the code as comments.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. Though I was just making a normal reply.

Comment: How did you come about "armv5tejl-unknown-linux-gnueabihf" being the correct option for your target?

Comment: Hi !Please close this topic, I managed to solve it with some help here : https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/331

Comment: Well that was never the problem :) It's the toolchain that was delivered with the target system that I am developing my SW for.
Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it with some help here : [github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/331](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/331)
                    – Tias

> Right, I finally managed to make it run on my ARMv5 target by doing
>   the following, many thanks for pointing me to the ARM toolchain that
>   contained the nosys.spec & libnosys.a files  :
>
> - Downloaded ARM toolchain
>     `gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3-20150921-linux.tar.bz2` from
>     https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded
> - Downloaded `libsodium-1.0.7` from https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/
>
> Note: This is for making a static
>   `libsodium.a`
>
> Example below assuming home folder =
>   `/home/user`
>
> ```
> tar xvjf gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3-20150921-linux.tar.bz2
> tar xvzf libsodium-1.0.7.tar.gz
> cp ./gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3/arm-none-eabi/lib/nosys.spec ./libsodium-1.0.7/
> cp ./gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q3/arm-none-eabi/lib/libnosys.a ./libsodium-1.0.7/
> ```
>
> Folder gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-can
>   be deleted at this point.
>
> ```
> cd ./libsodium-1.0.7/
> mkdir ARMv5
> export LDFLAGS='-static -g --specs=nosys.specs -L/home/user/libsodium-1.0.7/ -lnosys -lc'
> ./configure --host=armv5tejl-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --enable-static --prefix=/home/user/libsodium-1.0.7/ARMv5/
> make DESTDIR=/home/user/libsodium-1.0.7/ARMv5/
> ```
>
> Key
>   discoveries for me :
>
> - Hint from jedisct1 where to get the
>     ARM toolchain containing both the `nosys.spec` and
>     `libnosys.a` files.
> - Found out to add linker flag
>     `-lc` to make libsodium with libc (contaning
>     `__libc_start_main`, `abort`,
>     `__libc_csu_fini` and `__libc_csu_init`)